# Replicating values in R by group

Tags: arrays, r, loops, dplyr

I have a data set containing a measurement and the specific day it was collected. I would like to replicate the values between days, up until the last measurement day. For example, here is the data before it is replicated:

```
           Measurement    Day
Subject1   .86            1            
Subject1   .91            7            
Subject1   .83            9            
Subject2   .77            0            
Subject2   .82            5            
Subject2   .86            12
```

I would like to modify the data set above in R to look like the following:

```
           Measurement    Day
Subject1   .86            1
Subject1   .86            2
Subject1   .86            3
Subject1   .86            4
Subject1   .86            5 
Subject1   .86            6           
Subject1   .91            7
Subject1   .91            8            
Subject1   .83            9            
Subject2   .77            0
Subject2   .77            1
Subject2   .77            2
Subject2   .77            3
Subject2   .77            4       
Subject2   .82            5          
Subject2   .82            6
Subject2   .82            7     
Subject2   .82            8     
Subject2   .82            9     
Subject2   .82            10
Subject2   .82            11                      
Subject2   .86            12
```

I figure this can be done with the dplyr or data.table packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `complete`.  Assuming that the OP's input data is `matrix` (because `data.frame` doesn't allow duplicate row names and assuming that there is row.names - wow lot of assumptions), create a data.frame with `as.data.frame` while `cbind`ing the row.names as a column, grouped by 'Subject', use `complete` to get the full sequence of 'Day' and then `fill` the NAs in 'Measurement' with the non-NA previous value

```
library(tidyverse)    
cbind(Subject = row.names(dat), as.data.frame(dat)) %>%
   group_by(Subject) %>%
   complete(Day = first(Day):last(Day)) %>%
   fill(Measurement) %>%
   select(Subject, Measurement, Day)
# A tibble: 22 x 3
# Groups:   Subject [2]
#   Subject  Measurement   Day
#   <fct>          <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Subject1        0.86     1
# 2 Subject1        0.86     2
# 3 Subject1        0.86     3
# 4 Subject1        0.86     4
# 5 Subject1        0.86     5
# 6 Subject1        0.86     6
# 7 Subject1        0.91     7
# 8 Subject1        0.91     8
# 9 Subject1        0.83     9
310 Subject2        0.77     0
# … with 12 more rows
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(c(0.86, 0.91, 0.83, 0.77, 0.82, 0.86, 1, 7, 9, 0, 5, 
12), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Subject1", "Subject1", 
"Subject1", "Subject2", "Subject2", "Subject2"), c("Measurement", 
"Day")))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> foo = function(x){
+     r = range(x)
+     as.numeric(seq(r[1], r[2]) %in% x)
+ }
> do.call(rbind, lapply(split(1:NROW(dat), row.names(dat)), function(i){
+     temp = dat[i,]
+     temp = temp[with(rle(cumsum(foo(temp[,"Day"]))), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)),]
+     temp[,"Day"] = ave(temp[, "Day"], temp[,"Day"], FUN = function(x) x + (1:length(x) - 1))
+     temp
+ }))
         Measurement Day
Subject1        0.86   1
Subject1        0.86   2
Subject1        0.86   3
Subject1        0.86   4
Subject1        0.86   5
Subject1        0.86   6
Subject1        0.91   7
Subject1        0.91   8
Subject1        0.83   9
Subject2        0.77   0
Subject2        0.77   1
Subject2        0.77   2
Subject2        0.77   3
Subject2        0.77   4
Subject2        0.82   5
Subject2        0.82   6
Subject2        0.82   7
Subject2        0.82   8
Subject2        0.82   9
Subject2        0.82  10
Subject2        0.82  11
Subject2        0.86  12
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly based on @akrun 's answer

```
 library(tidyverse)

    df <- cbind(Subject = row.names(dat), as.data.frame(dat))

    df %>% group_by(Subject) %>% 
      mutate(day_diff = c(diff(Day), 1)) %>% 
      uncount(day_diff) %>% 
      mutate(Day = first(Day):last(Day)) %>% 
      ungroup()
```